# Export values to Excel file format

Tags: php, excel

Hello I having trouble exporting values from  an array to excel for example how would I 
export the following:

```
echo "<table ' border='1' >"
    echo "<th>ComputerName</th>"));
    echo "<th>SerialNumber</th>";
    echo "<th>SystemModel</th>";
    echo "<th>DateTime</th>";
    echo "<th>Software</th>";
    echo "<th>Hardware</th>";
    echo "<th>Support</th>";
    echo "<th>Delete</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

$alt_color = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

  {
    error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    //foreach( $array_values as $value )
 $bgc = ( $alt_color % 2 ? 'Dark' : 'Light' );
     echo "<tr class=".$bgc.">";
    //echo "<td><a href=\"update.php?LSUserID=" .$row['LSUserID']."\">" .$row['LSUserID']."</a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href=\"update.php?LSUserID=" .$row['LSUserID']."\">" .$row['ComputerName']."</a></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['SerialNumber'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['SystemModel'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['DateTime'] . "</td>";
```

Comment: Write it to a file named spreadsheet.xls? Believe it or not, Excel will open an HTML table as a spreadsheet.

Comment: wouldn't a csv file be better, greater compatibility and built in php tools.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need the appropriate headers (the ones below are from an [example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#76749) in the PHP docs)

```
$export = "my_name.xls";  

header('Pragma: public'); 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// prevent caching....
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Date in the past sets the value to already have been expired.
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");    
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); 
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');     // HTTP/1.1 
header('Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0');    // HTTP/1.1 
header ("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// end of prevent caching....
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: none'); 
// This should work for IE & Opera
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;');  
 // This should work for the rest
header("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");     
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($export).'"');
```

After that, your code should work with a couple of modifications (Excel can read HTML structures):

```
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); // you shouldn't have that in the loop.
                                    // you actually should put this first
echo "<table >"
    // the rest of your table opening code.

$alt_color = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
     echo "<tr>";
     // the rest of your columns.
     echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

If that does not work, for some reason, then you can create a CSV, but you need to worry about escaping it:

```
// add all of the headers.
echo '"ComputerName","SerialNumber","SystemModel",'; //etc for all columns.

// row makes sure that there is only one set of values.
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
if( !$row ) die(); // no value found. exit.
echo getCSVRow( $row );
do // do...while lets us handle the \n more gracefully.
{
    echo "\n". getCSVRow( $row );
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result));

function getCSVRow( array $row )
{
    $ret = "";
    foreach( $row as $val )
        $ret .= '"' . escapeCSV( $val ) . '",';
    return sustr( $ret, 0, strlen( $ret ) ); // clear the tailing comma
}

function escapeCSV( $str )
{
    return str_replace( '"', '\"', $str );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use php-excel library for reading and writing data in excel. Find below link:

- http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/
- http://code.google.com/p/php-excel/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-phpexcel/

Answer (score 1):

I have found a tool heavily inspired from Google's AppInventor to create database exports in an PHP/mySQL enviroment.
inspect the site: http://www.freegroup.de/software/phpBlocks/demo.html

Comment: Needs a little bit clearer of an explanation, but the link does seem to go to a valid software technique.  @Andreas generally you should try to flesh out a post more than just having a link in it, especially starting out on stack overflow, due to the prevalence of linkspam bots.

Answer (score 0):

With phpBlock you can create your db->excel export in a drag drop environment which is inspired from OpenBlock from MIT or AppInventor from Google. 
This means it is not necessary to code anything in PHP.

But the export feature is only one possibility of the php-lib. You can use this lib as a dynamic extension to your existing PHP application. Like dyn. formula or calculation.
I hope this more clear than the posting before.