# how to export report in word or excel

Tags: php, html

i want to export this report format in word or excel please help me. with this code i am getting proper data from database now i want to export it.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="daily.php">
 <h1 style="padding-left:150px;"> Daily Report </h1>
 <div class="report" style="overflow:auto;height:400px;">
 <?php $q="select cid,gtotal from db_transaction where tdate='$dat'";
 $a=mysql_query($q);
 echo '<table border="1" class="curvedEdges">';
 echo '<th width="30">Sr </th><th> Customer Name </th> <th>Services </th>    <th>Service By </th> <th> Amount</th>';
 $i=1;$gd=0;
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($a))
 {
     $qa=mysql_query("select cname from db_customers where cid=$row[0]");
     $cnm=mysql_fetch_array($qa);
      $sd=mysql_query("select service,price from db_sale_service where cid=$row[0]");
    echo '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td><td>'.strtoupper($cnm[0]).'</td><td><table><th>Name</th><th>Price</th>';
    while($snm=mysql_fetch_array($sd))
    {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$snm[0].'</td> <td>'.$snm[1].'</td></tr>';
    }
    $sd=mysql_query("select serviceby from db_sale_service where cid=$row[0]");
    $snm=mysql_fetch_array($sd);
    echo '</table></td><td>'.$snm[0].'</td><td>'.$row[1].'</td></tr>';
    $i++; $gd+=$row[1];
}
 echo '<tr><td colspan="3" align="center"><strong>Tolday\'s Total </strong></td><td colspan="2" align="center"><strong>'.$gd.'</strong></td></tr>'; 
 echo '</table>';
    ?> </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export values to Excel file format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991284/export-values-to-excel-file-format)

Comment: If you want to export to word you can use the PHPWord library (phpword.codeplex.com). If you want to export to Excel you have two options: using the PHPExcel library (phpexcel.codeplex.com) or simply exporting to CSV (comma-separated values). The CSV will not allow you to do any formatting, so if you need formatting the PHPExcel library is your best bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this particular code snippet and modify as per your requirements.

```
<?PHP
  // Original PHP code by Chirp Internet: www.chirp.com.au
  // Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header.

  function cleanData(&$str)
  {
    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
  }

  // filename for download
  $filename = "website_data_" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
  header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

  $flag = false;
  $result = pg_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY field") or die('Query failed!');
  while(false !== ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    if(!$flag) {
      // display field/column names as first row
      echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
      $flag = true;
    }
    array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
  }
  exit;
?>
```

More at http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/dataexport/#.UbB-PECLA6I